# Add a location switch for my app under iphone location services

Tags: iphone, location, setting

I am going to add a switch setting under settings/LocationServices for my App.   I searched a lot posts and I can add a setting under settings(of course, the Xcode has a template called settings bundle which is aimed to do it). But my problem is how can I add a location setting under settings/LocationServices ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is automatically done for you if the app uses core location.

Comment: I am going to add a location service for my app, I would like to upload the GPS data to a webservice every minute.  I want to know  will the location be triggered even my app is closed?

Comment: From the developer documentation: "An app that provides continuous location updates to the user (even when in the background) can enable background location services by including the UIBackgroundModes key (with the location value) in its Info.plist file. The inclusion of this value in the UIBackgroundModes key does not preclude the system from suspending the app, but it does tell the system that it should wake up the app whenever there is new location data to deliver. Thus, this key effectively lets the app run in the background to process location updates whenever they occur."